# Creating new Window while coming from a background worker

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, backgroundworker

I don't think I've quite found what I'm looking for, and unsure if possible...  I've worked with background workers to do processes and during certain "ProgressChanged" events to pull messages from the background worker and update a given window dialog.  No problem.

New item...  During a certain process that I am trying to have running on a background worker, depending on certain condition, I need it to actually call up a new Window dialog to get user input before resuming its operation...  In pseudo format..

```
Start Window
Click Button For Action
Create BackgroundWorker (BGW) and enable progress changed
Link BGW "ProgressChanged" to CurrentWindowCheckProgress method
run BGW process
```

In the BGW, under certain condition, I update the progress and have a flag on the BGW that I need specific dialog X to be shown to the user.  So, via the ReportProgress(), the hook to the CurrentWindowCheckProgress method is hit (which is on the UI thread).  This method sees the flag and needs to create a new Window(), get answer from that, THEN return back to the BGW thread to continue.

So far, all the logic works as planned, but I'm getting an error

"The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."

So, how / what do I need to do to show the user my interim form "TestPromptWindow".

This is C#, WPF, VS2010, .Net 4.0

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to show the TestPromptWindow?

Comment: It sure doesn't sound like you actually use the ProgressChanged event.  Which can't work as you describe, calling ReportProgress() doesn't block the BGW thread.  You are going to have to use Dispatcher.Invoke() inside the worker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not what backgroundworkers are designed for. The messaging BGW does for you is completely asynchronous. Technically it is posssible to use Control.Invoke to run code on the UI thread, but it could be that this Invoke call is run out of order with your progress updates, as it may have a different message priority.

The next release of .net will provide very nice support for this. meanwhile, you can use the `Task` class, especcially its `continueWith` member. [Here](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/10/26/parallelism-in-net-part-19-taskcontinuationoptions/) is a nice example showing how to go back and forth to the UI thread.

Comment: Sorry so late in response... After getting task going, I completely blanked coming back here for credit.

Answer (score 1):

Could you show the content of `CurrentWindowCheckProgress`? I'm not sure how you prevent the `BackgroundWorker` from working while presenting the window to the user. The error looks like if you were trying to do some UI code on a non-UI thread. If that's the case try to invoke this piece of code using `Dispatcher.Invoke(...)` method.